# Polymer 3 CORS with iron-ajax

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, iron-ajax

I am trying to make an get call using [iron-ajax](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-ajax) as follows:

```
<iron-ajax
    id="getLogsAjax"
    url="http://localhost:51806/{{logPath}}"
    method="get"
    handle-as="text"
    last-response="{{logResponse}}">
 </iron-ajax>
```

But am getting the following error:
***No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access***

I see this was solved on [an older version of Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130939/how-to-solve-no-access-control-allow-origin-in-polymer-project) but the **byutv-jsonp** library used there is now outdated. Any idea how to solve this with Polymer 3.0?

Comment: Try to change your url to : `./{{logPath}}`.